# Finding two generators for a finite intersection of maximal ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4399584/generators-of-a-finite-intersection-of-maximal-ideals) question asks the following question:
In the polynomial $k$-algebra $A$, in $d$ variables over a field $k=\bar k$, is it true that any finite intersection of maximal ideals is generated by $d$ elements?

That question has a positive answer by Harm Derksen, and I wish to understand his answer.

Let us concentrate on the two-dimensional case $d=2$ and $k=\mathbb{C}$, namely $A=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
By the Nullstellensatz, every maximal ideal is of the form $\langle x-\alpha, y-\beta \rangle$, for some $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}$.

> How do we actually find these two generators for a concrete finite intersection of maximal ideals? Could one please apply the method explained in Harm Derksen's answer in the following example:
> $M_1=\langle x,y \rangle$ and $M_2=\langle x-1,y-2 \rangle$;
> I see four generators for $I=M_1 \cap M_2$:
> $\{ x(x-1),x(y-2),y(x-1),y(y-2) \}$.

**My attempt to apply the method in Derksen's answer:**
$n=2$. $P_1=(0,0), P_2=(1,2)$. $P_1=(Q_1,r_1), P_2=(Q_2,r_2)$, so $Q_1=0,r_1=0,Q_2=1,r_2=2$ (here there are only two coordinates, so we can just write $q_1,q_2$ instead of $Q_1,Q_2$). Here we can take as the linear change of coordinates the identity, since $q_1,q_2$ are already distinct. By the induction hypothesis, there exists a polynomial $f_1 \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ *that generates the finite intersection of which $n-1$ maximal ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x]$?*
The maximal ideal $\langle x-q_1 \rangle$?
So $f_1(x)=x-q_1=x-0=x$? Using [polynomial interpolation](https://polynomial%20interpolation) we can construct a polynomial $g=g(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $g(q_1)=r_1$ and $g(q_2)=r_2$ ($g$ is of degree $1$ and it it easy to see that it must be the line $g(x)=2x$ because $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=2$).
Now take $f_2=f_2(x,y)=y-g(x)=y-2x$.
The zero set of $f_1=x,f_2=y-2x$ is the set $\{P_1=(0,0)\}$.
But $\langle f_1,f_2 \rangle = \langle x,y-2x \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle$ is not the intersection of
$M_1=\langle x,y \rangle$ and $M_2=\langle x-1,y-2 \rangle$...

The gap in my understanding is who are the $n-1$ maximal ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x]$? I do not inderstand why we cannot take all the $n$ points $q_1,q_2$ or in other words, $f_1$ that generates $\langle x \rangle \cap \langle x-1 \rangle$ is $f_1=f_1(x)=x(x-1)$.
Then is $\langle f_1,f_2 \rangle = \langle x(x-1),y-2x \rangle$ the intersection of
$M_1=\langle x,y \rangle$ and $M_2=\langle x-1,y-2 \rangle$?
I see why $\langle x(x-1),y-2x \rangle \subseteq M_1 \cap M_2$.
The other direction probably holds as well.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The linked answer outlines exactly how to find two generators: polynomial interpolation. If you have questions about what that means, you should be more explicit in your post here.

Comment: @KReiser, thank you. Ok, I will edit my question as you suggest. Indeed, my question is about the method explaind in Harm Derksen's answer.